# How to mock a throw with jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

What is wrong on this test below?

```
test('should throws if validator throws', () => {
      const sut = new EmailValidatorAdapter()
      jest.spyOn(validator, 'isEmail').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
          throw new Error()``
    })
      const response = sut.isValid('invalid@email.com')
      expect(response).toThrow()
  })
```

I am trying to make sure that the EmailValidatorAdapter throws if its email validator dependence throws. So then I'm going to treat on controller layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sut.isValid()` calls `validator.isEmail()`, the mock implementation that you provided throws an exception, `sut.isValid()` never returns and, `response` is not set and the `expect(response).doWhatever()` is not executed. Instead, Jest catches the exception and concludes that your test failed.

When you expect an exception to be thrown you don't call the function yourself. Instead, you pass to `expect()` the function that throws or a function that calls the function that throws and it calls it for you.

Like this:

```js
it('throws if validator throws', () => {
  const sut = new EmailValidatorAdapter()
  jest.spyOn(validator, 'isEmail').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    throw new Error();
  });

  expect(() => sut.isValid('invalid@email.com')).toThrow();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it like that, it usually works for me.

```
test('should throws if validator throws', () => {
  const sut = new EmailValidatorAdapter()
  jest.spyOn(validator, 'isEmail').mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    throw new Error()
  })
  const response = sut.isValid('invalid@email.com')
  expect(response).toEqual(new Error('error_text'))
})
```

The `new Error('error_text')` can be changed to the exception you are trying to mock, like new `BadRequestException('error_text')`.

Comment: Thx, i've already tryed this, but what if a developer treat the exception at the EmailValidatorAdapter returning the Error object? The propose to only treat the exception on controller layer would not be 'forced' toward a other 'new developer' in the project...